# Azure Devops Build pipeline failed

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops pipeline failed with below error:

Couldn't load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsZmb.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops Build pipeline failed

To resolve this issue, you should make sure if the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` in the bin directory after you build the project.

You could get AjaxControlToolkit.dll and add `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` to your Reference folder(Right Click on Reference Folder  > `Add Reference` > browse  `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`)

Then set `Copy Local` to `True` and build & publish you project.